How to train DSPy on a custom spreadsheet dataset and create a chatbot
can someone give me an example of how I create a chatbot using DSPy with my dataset present in a spreadsheet? I want to train the DSPy with my spreadsheet. Also, I am using the local model Ollama mistral.
